# How can I create a custom MVC3 template or HTML helper for a property of type KeyValuePair<string,string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I've got a model with 3 properties that are of type KeyValuePair

```
public class TestModel {
    public KeyValuePair<string,string> MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

My Controller code is as follows,

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
     var model = new TestModel {MyProperty= new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Color", "Blue")};
     return View(model);
 }
```

If I use the following Razor code, my results are not what I want.

```
@model TestModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

My view ends up rendering:

MyProperty
Key
Color
Value
Blue

I'd like to create my own helper or template to override this functionality.  I attempted to create a custom template in the Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates as shown below, but it wasn't picked up.

```
@model KeyValuePair<string,string>
<label>This should show up</label>
```

Thanks for any and all comments/suggestion.

Comment: What is your template called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [**UIHint Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx) in your model to specify which DisplayTemplate you would like to use, for example:

```
public class TestModel 
{
    [UIHint("NameOfYourDisplayTemplate")]
    public KeyValuePair<string,string> MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

This would refer to the DisplayTemplate View named "NameOfYourDisplayTemplate", when rendering MyProperty.

Answer (score 1):

In your `TestModel` class decorate the `MyProperty` property with DataType Attribute, for example:

```
[DataType("KeyValuePair")]
public class TestModel {
    public KeyValuePair<string,string> MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

and then create your view as `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/KeyValuePair.cshtml`